# unique item view in Listview

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I have a ListView. Each view item in that Listview has a progress bar that will be updated by some threads. As The listview reuse the views (Has no unique view), the threads update unexpected views when new item has been added and when the listview has been scrolled.

I would like to know how can I create some unique views that each thread will update only the given view in the listview?

Answer (score 1):

Listview doesn't re-use the views by default like recyclerview does, because listview relies on implementers using the ViewHolder pattern to achieve the re-use. Simply don't use the viewholder pattern and each list item will receive its own view. Just be careful not to do this in a list with too many concurrent items. Viewholder became a defacto standard for a reason.

Comment: That's the problem. I cannot guarantee that the user will not put 25 items. To avoid memory leak. I prefer finding a way to manipulate the recycled views as unique.

Comment: First thought would be to maintain a list of views that are currently being updated by a background thread, and ensuring those are never recycled until the update is complete.

Comment: I have tried that technique but unsuccessful. I know I can do some stuff in the getView() from my adapter. But, when the listview  has been scroll, some item added or remove, getView() get call and I cannot return null. I have compared the item at the actual position and return the view in the actual background task but, that view got duplicated or replaced other one. seems like Android reuses my thread view.

Comment: I thought about adding headerview but, cannot add header after setting the adapter to the listview.

Comment: My actual code almost works by putting a listener in the getView() and comparing the item in the getView() with the item in the actual thread. If the items are equals, Ok the thread will update the view getting from the listener callback. My only problem is, when I scroll the listview, I got another view updating by the the thread with the same progress as the expected one. And I cannot understand how can it update the view even if the items are not equals.

Comment: That would be helpful, if you know how can I say to Android, handle some views and do not touch some views because I want to handle them myself

Comment: You may not be able to completely separate the list in such a fashion to where android tries to handle some of it but you handle others. You may need to look into extending listview and overriding some of its methods so the OS is always calling your code. Good luck.

Comment: Indeed, I just had to read the Android Api a little. What I had to use was [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had just to take a look at that [class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html). Put the view that will be updated in the header list. When done, put it back to the adapter.